# hibernate Annotation Config not finding my xml file

Tags: java, hibernate

I have some inherited code that uses hibernate.  I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: C:\dev\wk\rs.110-AQU-120.cca.cca-ui\main\config\hibernate\DEV\master.cfg.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:1402)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1424)
    at com.cca.persistence.HibernateUtil$Parameters.<init>(HibernateUtil.java:96)
    at com.cca.persistence.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:137)
    ... 4 more
```

This occurs when calling AnnotationConfiguration()#configure(String configurationFile);
But the file does exist.  Why would hibernate not be able to locate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to your ressource must not be a absolute path (`C:\dev\wk\rs.110-AQU-120.cca...`), it must be the relative path within your application, like the package name!

The reason is, that `org.hibernate.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream` load the resorce by  `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(<resourceName>)`.

For more details, have a look at [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29), and [ClassLoader.getResource](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I didn't realize that the directory had to be set in the class path.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a configuration file at a custom location, you can cast `AnnotationConfiguration` to `Configuration`, and provide a `File` as an argument, for example:

```
((Configuration) cfg).configure(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/config/hibernate.cfg.xml"));
```